# Entering data to sections into a list

Tags: ios, xcode, list, listview

I am building a grocery app in IOS in Xcode and I am having trouble with lists.
In the list view, I want the user to be able to enter data and change already entered data in seprate sections of the list.
I have watch a few tutorials but non seem to answer my qeustion

How can I do this ?